# Creating laravel apps without internet connection

Tags: laravel-5.1

Does laravel 5.1 work without internet connection?
I like to create a laravel new application 
when i execute laravel new test (with intenet connection) it works well;
but when i execute similar command in the same directory (new anotherName) without internet connection it doesn't work and the nest error message is shown

```
  [GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException]                                      
  Error creating resource. [url] http://cabinet.laravel.com/latest.zip [type]  
   2 [message] fopen(http://cabinet.laravel.com/latest.zip): failed to open s  
  tream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not kn  
  own [file] /home/<Myname>/.composer/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Adapter/Str  
  eamAdapter.php [line] 367
```

Is there a solution because i can't work online always?

Answer (score 4):

When you use the laravel installer it fetches the latest version from the server. One solution would be to initialise a Laravel project, then add it to git version control and then when offline checkout the project to a new folder. You'd have to manually choose a new app key (I think). You will also not be able to `composer require` or `npm install` any new packages while offline.

Once you have created it though it should run offline (unless your views are sourcing assets from, say, bootstrap or jQuery CDNs).

Answer (score 0):

Composer 2+:

```sh
COMPOSER_DISABLE_NETWORK=1 laravel new myapp
```

Troubleshooting:

1. Check your composer **version**: `composer --version` - you may have to update to the latest version with `composer self-update`;
2. Check you have a global **cache**: `echo $COMPOSER_HOME` - you may have to create a `~/.composer` and set `export COMPOSER_HOME="${HOME}/.composer"` to your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` - don't forget to close and open your terminal to apply the changes;
3. If you get this error `https://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded (Network disabled, request canceled: https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json), package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date`, the laravel packages are not in the global cache. Run the command with internet enabled to download the files.